# fgetc() returns EOF when stream is not 0

Tags: c, fseek, fgetc

I'm trying to read characters from a binary file and compare them to characters from another binary file, but I want to start reading one of the files from the middle, not the beginning. When I try it, I can't read the file I'm trying to read from the middle because it immediately returns EOF. I tried to read it from different points, even moving the stream just a single place but it still returned EOF straight away.

```
int scanWithOffset(FILE* fc, FILE* fv, int start, int end)
{
    int charRead1 = 0, charRead2 = 0, matchCounter = 0, match = 0;
    int fileSize = findFileSize(fv);
    int counter = 0;

    if (!fseek(fc, start, SEEK_SET))
    {
        while (((charRead2 = fgetc(fv)) != EOF) && ((charRead1 = fgetc(fc)) != EOF)
               && !match && counter < (end - start))
        {
            counter++;
            if (charRead1 == charRead2)
            {
                matchCounter++;
                if (matchCounter == fileSize)
                {
                    match = 1;
                    fclose(fc);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // if something doesn't match up, reset the counter and bring
                // the stream back to the beginning
                matchCounter = 0; 
                fseek(fv, 0, SEEK_SET);
            }
        }

        if (!match)
        {
            fclose(fc);
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

Comment: Does is work if you drop the `fseek` alltogether?

Comment: It does work if I drop it, but I still need to read it from a certain part of the file, I can't just read it from the beginning to the end. I also fixed the typo and it did not help.

Comment: What happens if you call `scanWithOffset` with `start = 0`?

Comment: If I do that it works.

Comment: And with `start = 1`?

Comment: verify which file operation triggered the `EOF` signal. Could potentialy be either `fgetc(fc)` or `fgetc(fv)`... maybe print `ferror(fv)`?

Comment: start = 1 doesn't work

Comment: It was fgets(fc)

Comment: What is your platform and how do you open the files (show the lines with `fopen`)?

Comment: I'm on windows.
Here's the `fopen` line `currentFile = fopen(dirName, "r+b");`

Comment: I don't know if `fv` is set to the start of the file or not, maybe it is at the end and `fgetc(fv)` is returning `EOF`? In that case you should `fseek(fv, 0, SEEK_SET)` to go to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matchCounter == fileSize)
{
   match = 1;
   fclose(fc);
}
```

You do not break the `while` loop after closing `fc`. You have to exit the `while` loop when you reach `matchCounter == fileSize`. You can add `break;` after `fclose(fc)`:

```
if (matchCounter == fileSize)
{
   match = 1;
   fclose(fc);
   break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the actual cause of his problem.

Comment: This changes nothing, as after that if statement it goes back to the start of the while loop anyway and can't continue it due to match being true

Comment: @EgorMatuk why not, the condition of `match` is after `charRead1 = fgetc(fc)) != EOF` in `while` condition. It means you re-read the file before verifying the condition of `match`